# popToRootViewController crashes when called by UITabBarControllerDelegate

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` with 4 `UINavigationControllers`.  I have implemented the `didSelectViewController` Delegate Method as follows:

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    [(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

}
}
```

It crashes when a `NavigationController` is at a 2nd Level after `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` pushes a new viewController onto the stack.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

RootViewController *detailViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];

// ...    
detailViewController.title = [self.temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
detailViewController.sort = self.title;

// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];

}
```

Of course the debugger with `NSZombies` enabled doesn't give any feedback.

However, if I add retain to detailViewController alloc;

```
RootViewController *detailViewController = [[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil] retain];
```

It works, but leaks memory.

Any ideas what is wrong, how to fix, what is happening?

Comment: i have the exact same problem, any progress? it specifically only seems to happen when the view at the 2nd level is a uitableview.

Comment: it's the popped view controller that nszombies picks up. but i'm sure my memory management is right... i just alloc it, push it, then release it, like you do above.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar scenario and i came up with following solution.

In my application i have login screen at launch and then I have UITabbarController with 4 UINavigationControllers.

I have created property of UINavigationController in AppDelegate.h file.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Then

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions         (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
 //Override point for customization after application launch.
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Now when you need to pop to RootViewController then use following code

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

[((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope this solves your problem.